# XSL - Replace pipe by another character

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, oxygenxml

I use XSLT 2. How I can replace pipe by aonther character ?

For exemple I have an element like this :

```
<list items="A1|A2|A3"/>
```

I want to have

```
<list items="A1,A2,A3"/>
```

I tried something like this, but not working

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="replace(list/@items, '|', ',')"/>
```

What is problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `replace()` function uses regex - and the pipe character is a special character in regex. Either escape the character:

```
<xsl:variable name="result" select="replace(list/@items, '\|', ',')"/>
```

or use the `translate()` function instead.